# What are the advantages of using 2d arrays?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been working on a master handbook for a game using PHP for the past few months and one of which includes a table of all vehicles used by a certain group with their stats and restrictions. I've come to a junction when it comes to using arrays and although both work fine, I want to know the actual advantages to using 2d arrays as opposed to seperate arrays.

For instance, I can use individual variables and call the main array (the vehicle):

```
$facVehImage[0] = 'lcpd.png';
$facVehName[0] = 'LCPD Cruiser';
$facVehDesc[0] = 'Used by the LCPD.';
$facVehRank[0] = 'Officer';
$facVehDiv[0] = 'None';

$facVehImage[1] = 'vcpd.png';
$facVehName[1] = 'VCPD Cruiser';
$facVehDesc[1] = 'Used by the VCPD.';
$facVehRank[1] = 'Officer';
$facVehDiv[1] = 'None';
```

The variables will build a seperate table row in HTML according to my include line. Now, I could do this... but I've also managed to get it working with the following:

```
$facVeh[0][0] = 'lcpd.png';
$facVeh[0][1] = 'LCPD Cruiser';
$facVeh[0][2] = 'Used by the LCPD.';
$facVeh[0][3] = 'Officer';
$facVeh[0][4] = 'None';

$facVeh[1][0] = 'vcpd.png';
$facVeh[1][1] = 'VCPD Cruiser';
$facVeh[1][2] = 'Used by the VCPD.';
$facVeh[1][3] = 'Officer';
$facVeh[1][4] = 'None';
```

Of course using 2d arrays will mean I need to add an increment somewhere in the output file for it to properly work but other than that what really is the difference?

---

To clarify, I might've done this a very inefficient way. Data is fed through a separate script and builds a PHP file from that containing all the required variables (including arrays), which finally includes a HTML file. The HTML file (on the vehicles section) looks a bit like this (apologies for the mess):

```
<div class="fpVehicles">
    <span class="header">Vehicles</span>
    <table class="fpVehicleTable">
    <?php
        $facVehCount = 0;
        while ($facVehCount < $facVehLimit) {
            echo '<tr valign="top"><td class="fpVehicleImage"><img src="img/v/'.$facVehImage[$facVehCount].'" class="cVeh"></td>';
            echo '<td valign="top" class="fpVehInfoBox"><div class="fpVehInfoTitle">'.$facVehName[$facVehCount].'</div>';
            echo '<div class="fpVehInfoDesc">'.$facVehDesc[$facVehCount].'</div>';
            echo '<div class="fpVehInfoRank"><b>Rank:</b> '.$facVehRank[$facVehCount].'+</div>';
            echo '<div class="fpVehInfoDiv"><b>Division:</b> '.$facVehDiv[$facVehCount].'</div></td></tr>';
            $facVehCount++;
        }
    ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

The seperate echo lines exist from when I was testing 2d arrays and therefore needed to increment in-between. I'm aware I could use a multi-line echo (<<<) and just throw that in there but for the sake of it being changed shortly, I think it'd be a waste of cleaning.

Comment: Use whatever works for you.

Comment: I would say that adding extra code is a  big difference,and judging by array structure there would be more than onle line of code. I also advise you to check out [This](https://www.guru99.com/arrays.html) and [This](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) on the topic of PHP Associative Arrays. The associative type may be better to suit you needs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's about keeping your code meaningful, more organised, and more readable.

**Your Approach #1**

In the first example, you're making five separate variables which are all supposed to relate to each other. To get the properties of the first vehicle, you need to get:

```
$facVehImage[0]
$facVehName[0]
$facVehDesc[0]
$facVehRank[0]
$facVehDiv[0]
```

You're littering the place with multiple separate variables which are all supposed to related to one object.

**Your Approach #2**

It's easier and cleaner to use the second approach, where to get the properties of the vehicle you only need to get:

```
$facVeh[0]
```

Contained in there is everything you need to know about the vehicle. However, this is still bad code.

Nobody wants to have to remember what `$facVeh[0][3]` means. What property is `[3]`? If you forget, do you want to have to check through your code later to figure that out? What if someone else needs to work with your code? How will they know? What if you add a new property to your array later? The order changes and suddenly `[3]` isn't the rank anymore. Everything breaks and you need to change all your code.

---

**Alternative Approach (#3)**

An better way would be to use an associative array, which keeps all the properties of your vehicle in one place but labels them properly. This prevents the issues described above.

```
$facVeh = [
    'lcpd' => [
        'name'  => 'LCPD Cruiser',
        'desc'  => 'Used by the LCPD.',
        'image' => 'lcpd.png',
        'rank'  => 'Officer',
        'div'   => 'None'
    ],
    'vcpd' => [
        'name'  => 'VCPD Cruiser',
        'desc'  => 'Used by the VCPD.',
        'image' => 'vcpd.png',
        'rank'  => 'Officer',
        'div'   => 'None'
    ]
];
```

Now when you write `$facVeh['lcpd']['rank']` it makes total sense - much more sense than `$facVeh[0][3]`. You've also contained your vehicles nicely in one variable.

---

**Best Approach (#4)**

What you really want to do though, is use object oriented code. This is a big topic and outside of the scope of this answer, but you would have a `Vehicle` class and build multiple instances of it.

Basic example:

```
class FacVehicle
{

    public $name;
    public $desc;
    public $rank;
    public $image;
    public $div;

    public function __construct($name, $desc)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->desc = $desc;
    }
}

$lcpdVehicle = new FacVehicle('LCPD Cruiser', 'Used by the LCPD.');
$lcpdVehicle->rank = new OfficerRank();
$lcpdVehicle->image = 'lcpd.png';
```

---

**HTML Clean-up**

Some advice on cleaning up the HTML output, which also shows the benefits of using more semantic code:

```
<div class="fpVehicles">
    <span class="header">Vehicles</span>
    <table class="fpVehicleTable">
        <?php foreach ($facVehicles as $i => $vehicle) : ?>

        <tr valign="top">
            <td class="fpVehicleImage"><img src="img/v/<?= $vehicle['image']; ?>" class="cVeh"></td>
            <td valign="top" class="fpVehInfoBox">
                <div class="fpVehInfoTitle"><?= $vehicle['name']; ?></div>
                <div class="fpVehInfoDesc"><?= $vehicle['description']; ?></div>';
                <div class="fpVehInfoRank"><b>Rank:</b> <?= $vehicle['rank']; ?>+</div>';
                <div class="fpVehInfoDiv"><b>Division:</b> <?= $vehicle['div']; ?></div>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer has smashed my question out of the park. I've never actually used the arrays you've mentioned, where you assign names to them. I'm going to play about with them now. How easy is it to build these types of arrays through another script? Is it just a case of catching the variables and looping them through an extra array?

Comment: @Harrison I'd have to see your other code as I don't know what your other script is sending, but yes it should be easy to build the associative array in a programmatic way. You don't need to manually define the array. Is your other script sending the data via query parameters or something? I might be able to edit my answer with a solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly about style/architecture. If you have hard-coded data, then using 2 arrays in this case is fine; the main difference is using multiple variables instead of 1.

Say you have the following arrays;

```
$facVehImage[0] = 'lcpd.png';
$facVehName[0] = 'LCPD Cruiser';
```

You then need to display the data in this array like:

```
foreach ($facVehImage as $image) {
  echo $image; // or something like that
}

foreach ($facVehName as $name) {
  echo $name; // or something like that
}
```

Now you're running 2 loops, better to have 1 loop, so you'll end up doing something like;

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($facVehImage); $i++) {
  echo $facVehName[$i] . $facVehImage[$i];
}
```

The issue with that is when the 2 arrays differ in length (say you have 5 images, but only 4 names) PHP will output an error/notice saying it cannot find the index.

Using 1 multidimensional array is nicer, because it will allow you to use an array of associative (dictionary) arrays;

```
$vehicles[] = ['name'=>'foo', 'image'=>'bar'];
$vehicles[] = ['name'=>'faz', 'image'=>'baz'];
```

When outputting that in a table, your code will end up cleaner, an better readable;

```
foreach ($vehicles as $vehicle) {
  echo $vehicle['name'];
  echo $vehicle['image'];
}
```

Comment: I think I understand it after that explanation. For the record, the data is built by a seperate script that asks the user to input data and then builds on it from there. The html aspect looks a bit like what I've edited in my main question.

Answer (score 0):

With `multidimensional` or `2d` array, it's easy to access and maintain.

You don't have to use various variables for each entity which can reside in a single variable throughout your application.

Every variable created takes up a specific resource which when accessed has to be looked-up. Creating one 2d array is beneficial here.

A better way to create a 2d array in your case would be using `String` as key.

```
$facVeh[0]['VehImage'] = 'lcpd.png';
$facVeh[0]['VehName'] = 'LCPD Cruiser';
$facVeh[0]['VehDesc'] = 'Used by the LCPD.';
$facVeh[0]['VehRank'] = 'Officer';
$facVeh[0]['VehDiv'] = 'None';

$facVeh[1]['VehImage'] = 'vcpd.png';
$facVeh[1]['VehName'] = 'VCPD Cruiser';
$facVeh[1]['VehDesc'] = 'Used by the VCPD.';
$facVeh[1]['VehRank'] = 'Officer';
$facVeh[1]['VehDiv'] = 'None';
```

Please note, Do not assign numeric indexes `0`, `1`, `2`, etc manually. Create a loop to create it.

Comment: I originally used a variable inside the second array but quickly found it didn't work. Also yeah it's an automatic process, I have a script that runs where you input the requested data and it will automatically build a php file containing variables and finally include the HTML file. That way each file is dynamically created and the single HTML file can be changed once and affect every page (for instance, visuals).

Comment: All of them gave a good in-depth explanation. Many thanks friend!